# Proof of a "standard calculation"

Tags: calculus, inequality

I need to prove a "standard calculation":

If $r>0$ and $x\geq1$, then

$$-\varepsilon r + \varepsilon^2 (2x+r)^{3/2} \geq - \frac{r^2}{4(r+2x)^{3/2}}$$

$\forall \varepsilon \in [0,1]$.

I tried many ways to proove that, but I always find some restrictions in $\varepsilon$.

Thanks a lot for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(2x+r)^{3/2}=t$, then $t \geq 1$ (because $x \geq 1$ and $r>0$). So we have to show that for $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ 
$$\epsilon^2 t-\epsilon r +\frac{r^2}{4t} \geq 0.$$
Observe that the expression on the left is
$$\left(\epsilon\sqrt{t}-\frac{r}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)^2,$$
which is $\geq 0$ for all values of $\epsilon$ (not just in the interval given).

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to
 $$\left(\frac{r}{2(2x+r)^{3/4}}-\varepsilon(2x+r)^{3/4}\right)^{\!2}\ge 0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. A small detail is that  the exponents are $3/4$.

Comment: Oh! yes. I guess I messed up between my intermediate computations and the exponents in the O.P. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see this is that $\frac{r^2}{4(2x+r)^{3/2}} \in [0,1]$ is the vertex of the parabola $g(\epsilon) = -\epsilon r + \epsilon^2 (2x+r)^{3/2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to prove another property! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287011/calculation-of-an-inequality?noredirect=1#comment6762692_3287011