# calculation of an inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

If $x>1$, $r>0$, and $$F(x,r)=2 [ \sqrt{x+r}-\sqrt{x}]- 4[\sqrt[4]{x+r}-\sqrt[4]{x}],$$ I already prooved that $F(x,r) \geq 0$ because I can write it as

$$2[\underbrace{\sqrt[4]{x+r}-1}_A+\underbrace{\sqrt[4]{x}-1}_B]. [\underbrace{\sqrt[4]{x+r}-1-\sqrt[4]{x}+1}_C]$$
and $A, B, C$ are positive.

Now I must proove that $$F(x,r)- \frac{r^2}{4(r+2x)^\frac{3}{2}} \geq 0.$$

I know that it seems a standard calculation, but I can't conclude it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is $F(x,r)=2 [ \sqrt{x+r}-\sqrt{x}]- 4[\sqrt[4]{x+r}-\sqrt[4]{x}]$ the same as $F(x,r)=2 ( \sqrt{x+r}-\sqrt{x})- 4(\sqrt[4]{x+r}-\sqrt[4]{x})$?

Comment: Yes! You just changed [ ] by ( ).

Comment: OK. Then, I think that $F(x,y)$ is *not* equal to $2[{\sqrt[4]{x+r}-1}+{\sqrt[4]{x}-1}]. [{\sqrt[4]{x+r}-1+\sqrt[4]{x}+1}]$.

Comment: But it is. Just multipply and you will check that the identity is true.

Comment: When $(x,r)=(16,65)$, we have $F(x,y)=6\not=30=2[{\sqrt[4]{x+r}-1}+{\sqrt[4]{x}-1}]. [{\sqrt[4]{x+r}-1+\sqrt[4]{x}+1}]$.

Comment: I typped wrong! Thanks for showing me that! In the last [ ] we have $-\sqrt[4]{x}$!

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-It is equivalent to prove that
$$F(x,r)=\frac{4[2 ( \sqrt{x+r}-\sqrt{x})- 4(\sqrt[4]{x+r}-\sqrt[4]{x})](2x+r)^{\frac32}}{y^2}\ge1$$
It can be empirically verified that the function $F$ is increasing for values $x \gt1$ and $y \gt0$. Some particular values are:
$$F(1,0.001)\approx1.4142137\\F(1,0.01)\approx1.4122887\\F(1,0.1)\approx1.4156185\\F(1.01,1.01)\approx1.5272323$$
The first three values suggest that in $(x, y) = (1,0)$ there is a critical point and that in fact we always have $F (x, y)> 1$ for the $(x, y)$ considered. However to determine this with the derivatives of F (x, y) is revealed too difficult and perhaps impossible.

On the other hand the form of the function is such that the standard methodes to prove inequalities, they seem very arduous to apply.